# After asking 6 questions in 24 hours, display when the user should come back

Tags: feature-request

When asking more than 6 questions in 24 hours, a user gets the message

```
Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 6 questions in a 24 hour period
```

Could we please show "come back in X hours" in this message, where X is the number of hours a user needs to wait before posting?

Comment: `come back in X hours` <---. What's the context of your question?

Comment: @RobW - Sorry, provided more details.

Comment: I think the OP wants something like what is shown with the up/down votes, close votes, flags, etc. that tell you that you how much time you need to wait until you get the count reset.

Comment: If you want to ask more than 6 questions in 24 hours, then you probably need to step back and think more deeply about the project that you're working on.

Comment: @JackManey not necessarily, but I won't argue this here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until this feature is implemented, you can check the remainder by visiting your profile, and view the questions at the [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11236/ripper234?tab=questions&sort=newest) tab. Then open the question, and hover over "asked *n* hours ago", which shows a tooltip in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSZ` (`Z` is a marker for [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)).

24 hours (1 day) after the creation of the question, you can add a new question (don't forget to convert the shown time to your local time).

Comment: should you do a query to sort questions by time, and then look at the sixth newest question?

Comment: @Thufir Yes. I've updated the link in my answer, since it seems to have changed. In your case, the URL is: http://stackoverflow.com/users/262852/thufir?tab=questions&sort=newest